# How to add array items in one single item?

Tags: php, android, arrays, api, sorting

this is the code I am working on. I am creating an API for my mobile device.

```
<?php

$property_id=$_GET['property_id'];

$res_image=mysql_query("select * 
                        from fak_property_image 
                        where property_id='".$property_id."'");
$i=0;
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res_image)){

    // $status[$i]['property_id']=$row2['property_id'];
    // $status[$i]['image']=$row2['image'];
    $status[$i]['path']=$row2['path'];
    $i++;   
 }
echo json_encode( $status );exit;

?>
```

the output is following

```
[
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0008.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0009.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0013.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0015.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0016.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0074.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0210.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0211.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1400.1525441844.JPG"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1903.1525441844.jpg"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1904.1525441844.jpg"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1905.1525441844.jpg"},
{"path":"http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1906.1525441844.jpg"}
]
```

but my requirement is to display the output like this

```
[
    {
    "path":
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0008.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0009.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0013.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0015.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0016.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0074.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0210.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_0211.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1400.1525441844.JPG",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1903.1525441844.jpg",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1904.1525441844.jpg",:
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1905.1525441844.jpg",
        "http:\/\/grandthecompany.com\/admin\/uploads\/IMG_1906.1525441844.jpg"
    }
]
```

I have tried to fetch all the data using mysql_fetch_all but it is not working. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid JSON

Comment: ^ agree. Do you need `{"path":["url1","url2","url3"]}`?

Comment: Please, don't use the `mysql_*` functions. These functions are deprecated, and are removed in PHP 7. You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: `$status['path'][] = $row2['path'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$status['path'][] = $row2['path'];
```

Instead of:

```
$status[$i]['path']=$row2['path'];
```

But you definitely should use PDO, besides this code is vulnerable for SQL injections.